# What forces are acting on a massless pulley "cylinder"?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

So what I have learned is that when there is a string put over a pulley with tension $T$, the force on the pulley cylinder is going to be the sum of the tension forces from the string, but this doesn't seem to make sense to me. Why would that be true if the pulley is frictionless, and why does only the tension of the string matter? Also, why does the tension force act "away" from the pulley, but in the opposite direction when the tension is acting on a body as I drew in a picture. Doesn't that mean that they will cancel each other?

[image]

Comment: I assume the pulley is fixed rigidly?

Answer (score 0):

Picture incorrect a little bit. If you hold the loose end of the string, a tension T is there as shown on the right. Now this same tension on the other side will be pointing upwards. And the weight of the object $mg$ is pointing downwards. If $T = mg$, then system is stable.